# Simple Query has gone Serial after Optimisation, need it Parallel

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index-tuning, execution-plan

I've inherited a legacy system that has a Stored Procedure that supports a Web Application. It runs thousands of times a day. The application allows a user to enter partial Customer Details and the underlying Stored procedure will perform LIKE commands to return a shortlist of possible Customers to the Web-app.

It even allows the partial entry of a Customer ID (integer value), so if the value '123' is entered into the App, then the stored procedure should return all Customers with an ID containing '123' i.e. '612345' or '222123'.....yes I know crazy, typing in '1' returns an enormous dataset, but we can't change the App.

The search for the Customer ID is the slowest part of the stored procedure. I've "optimised" the stored procedure (in DEV) so it uses less IO and less CPU....but it's gone Serial and takes too long to run.....Help!

Here's how to re-create the problem.

```
--CREATE TEST TABLE
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
                        , Val Float
                        , CodeVal CHAR(100)
                        )
GO

--GENERATE A FEW MILLION TEST RECORD
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
SELECT
    RAND()
    ,CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID())
FROM 
    sys.objects --Contains 639 Rows
GO 10000

--CREATE INDEX ON ID FIELD
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON dbo.Test(ID)
```

The existing query performs a Parallel INDEX SCAN.

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20) = '123456'

--DROP TABLE #TMP1
CREATE TABLE #TMP1(ID INT)

INSERT INTO #TMP1
SELECT  ID 
FROM    dbo.Test
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ID) LIKE '%'+@ID+'%'
```

Then I realised that if a User enters a partial Customer ID of '123456', then the result-set can never contain a value smaller than '123456'. So I added an extra line to the Code (see below), now I have an INDEX SEEK with reduced IO and reduced CPU time. But to my horror it's gone Serial so now it takes forever. If this goes live then the user's wait time will jump from 4 seconds to 20 seconds.

```
INSERT INTO #TMP1
SELECT  ID 
FROM    dbo.Test
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ID) LIKE '%'+@ID+'%'
AND     ID >= @ID   --New line of code
```

I've now reached the point where I'm blindly coding in the hope it will go parallel.

Can anyone please explain Why this is happening (apart from the stock answer of "the optimiser decided it was better")?

And can anyone figure out how to make the query go parallel?

Trace flag 8649 is not an option for me.

And I've already read this very helpful article by [Paul White](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

It looks like the example provided produces varying results depending on a combination of System Spec and Row count on test table.

Apologies if you can't recreate the problem. 
But this is part of the answer to my problem.

**UPDATE:(Execution Plan)**

Aaron: Sorry about by example being frustrating if it doesn't work on your system.(I'm unable to share my company's actual execution plan for InfoSec reasons)

I've recreated the issue on my home system.

Here's the Execution Plan, (I'll upload full to Post-the-Plan)
[image]

my current row-count of dbo.Test is 2124160, the Non Clustered Index has 2627 Pages and 0.04% Fragmentation, below is my stats info.

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
Table 'Test'. Scan count 3, logical reads 2652, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 688 ms,  elapsed time = 368 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.
Table 'Test'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1106, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 281 ms,  elapsed time = 302 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

The stored procedure is used about 5000 times a day by Call-centre staff dealing with customers. An increased wait of 16 seconds will cost just over 22 hours per day of staff waiting for a result. At a shift time of 8 hours, this equates to 3 full time staff costing approximately £36k annually. There goes the money to upgrade to SQL Sentry licenses (big fan), we currently have Spotlight (still a good product) but I want something with greater depth.

**UPDATE: (Magic Number)**

With 12,000 Rows both Queries were serial.

With 2,124,160 Rows one query goes parallel.

With 66,000,000 Rows both go parallel.

There is definitely a rule/metric that the optimiser uses, and it is different if you have an Index Scan or Index Seek. *Does this mean that converting a query from Scan to Seek can have an adverse effect on tables/indexes of a certain size?*

**UPDATE: (Solution)**

Thanks Joe, you were spot-on with Max Degree of Parallelism.

I used:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@ID  = 1))
```

UNKNOWN didn't do the trick for my environment.

For anyone who's interested here's a useful article by [Kendra Little](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/).

Comment: Have you seen this? Is using dbo.MakeParallel an option for you? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2013/07/11/next-level-parallel-plan-porcing.aspx

Comment: Well I'm not sure you can blame "taking forever" on the plan going serial. I suspect it is going serial because the additional clause allowed it to seek, in which case there might not be any benefit at all to going parallel. But even a serial range scan shouldn't "take forever" - I'm not convinced that is your actual problem. Are you sure it isn't being blocked or running into another ["runaway query" cause](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-the-runaway-query/)?

Comment: (And FWIW I don't get a parallel plan on the first insert anyway - and both queries complete in about 10 seconds for me.)

Comment: I've used Adam Machanic's function to force Parallel and it worked, but it had it's own overhead that made it slower. So to try and see how it would perform on the Live environment I added a few more Million records to my Test table. Eventually the Optimised query started going parallel of it's own accord. It appears that once the Row count goes past a certain number then the query goes Parallel. Now I need to figure out what the magic Row/Page count is and see if it's above or below the Live system.

Comment: The Magic Row/Page count might vary per System. Thanks for your help Erik, it sent me in a positive direction that helped me out.

Comment: Question Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're running into issues with the [cost threshold for parallelism](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188603(v=sql.105).aspx) parameter.

> Use the cost threshold for parallelism option to specify the threshold at which Microsoft SQL Server creates and runs parallel plans for queries. SQL Server creates and runs a parallel plan for a query only when the estimated cost to run a serial plan for the same query is higher than the value set in cost threshold for parallelism.
>
> Longer queries usually benefit from parallel plans; the performance advantage negates the additional time required to initialize, synchronize, and terminate parallel plans. The cost threshold for parallelism option is actively used when a mix of short and longer queries is run. The short queries run serial plans, whereas the longer queries use parallel plans. The value of cost threshold for parallelism determines which queries are considered short, and they should therefore be run using serial plans.

On my test machine `cost threshold for parallelism` has the default value of 5. Below is a table of `MAXDOP 1` costs for the old and the new query:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║  Rows   ║ Cost of Old Query ║ Cost of New Query ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║   12000 ║ 0.037717          ║ 0.0199238         ║
║ 1610200 ║ 6.28954           ║ 1.86659           ║
║ 4610200 ║ 17.9959           ║ 6.46108           ║
╚═════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

As expected, with 1610200 rows the old query goes parallel but the new query goes serial. This is because the DOP 1 cost was above 5 so it qualified for a parallel plan. SQL Server estimated a lower cost for the parallel plan so it went parallel. With 4610200 rows both queries go parallel. You may see slightly different results on your machine.

There are two things working against you getting a parallel plan here. The first is that SQL Server has no way of knowing that this query is essential for your business and that you want to throw as many resources at it as possible. It doesn't know about your estimates that your organization could lose tens of thousands of dollars. It just views it as another cheap/trivial query. The second is that the query optimizer will always assign the query the same estimated cost regardless of the value of `@ID`. It uses default estimates because you're working with a variable. You could work around that with a `RECOMPILE` hint, but if this runs thousands of times per day that may not be the best idea.

My recommendation is to use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` query hint to increase the estimated number of rows from the clustered index seek. That will increase the cost of the plan and should make it more likely to use a parallel plan. From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> OPTIMIZE FOR ( @variable_name { UNKNOWN | = literal_constant } [ , ...n ] )
>
> Instructs the query optimizer to use a particular value for a local variable when the query is compiled and optimized. The value is used only during query optimization, and not during query execution.
>
> @variable_name
>
> Is the name of a local variable used in a query, to which a value may be assigned for use with the OPTIMIZE FOR query hint.
>
> literal_constant
>
> Is a literal constant value to be assigned @variable_name for use with the OPTIMIZE FOR query hint. literal_constant is used only during query optimization, and not as the value of @variable_name during query execution. literal_constant can be of any SQL Server system data type that can be expressed as a literal constant. The data type of literal_constant must be implicitly convertible to the data type that @variable_name references in the query.

For your query, you can optimize for a value of `'1'`. That should increase the cost of the plan quite a bit. In fact, in my testing this made the query have the same estimated cost as the old one without the filter. This makes sense because SQL Server will not be able to filter out any rows with a predicate of `ID > '1'`. If you use this hint you should experience the same parallel/serial behavior as before the code change.

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20) = '123456';

CREATE TABLE #TMP1 (ID INT);

INSERT INTO #TMP1 -- cost is 96.8547
SELECT  ID 
FROM    dbo.Test
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ID) LIKE '%'+@ID+'%'
AND     ID >= @ID  
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@ID = '1'));
```

[image: query plans]

Note that this hint may have negative effects if the query becomes more complex. Artificially inflating the estimated row count can cause a larger than necessary query memory grant, for example. If your production data is large enough such that the hint isn't needed I recommend not using it. If your query in production is different than the one listed in the question test carefully before using.

Comment: I still think that "make the query not run forever" and "make the query go parallel" are two separate goals, and the latter is not necessarily required to achieve the former. In other words, I don't think that the reason for the query to go super slow was caused by the fact that it wasn't running in parallel, I think there was something else going on (which may be why I can't reproduce the problem on three different systems), and the fact that making it parallel "fixed it" might just be a coincidence with the generation of a different plan.

Comment: Exaggerating 20 seconds to "takes forever" is not helpful at all, it's rather chicken little-ish. I'm mostly of the opinion that hints should be avoided if they can be, and I still think there is something else going on here (again, I couldn't reproduce the discrepancy on my systems, so I'd have to see actual plans from the OP to try to diagnose).

Comment: Updated Question with Stats and Query Plan. I've still got to work through your answer, will feedback soon.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll test it on Monday and feed back. Thanks. +1

Comment: @Joe: Is this a possible Downside? If the query had a DISTINCT then it would reserve pages for the sort "stolen pages", but too many pages would be stolen because the estimated number of rows would be over-exaggerated.

Comment: @pacreely I added a paragraph to my answer about that